# A Stack Exchange site for internship/job application questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

There are so many Stack Exchange sites so I wanted to ask: is there one where I can go and ask questions about job applications etc.? Or perhaps some non-career-specific one where I can ask questions about job applications? (Programming-related internship)

Comment: [The Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) has an [\[applications\]](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/tags/applications/info) tag. Based on the way you worded this question, I'm not sure if your question(s) would be on-topic there though. Make sure to go through the Help Center before posting.

Comment: It sounds like a good idea for [a new site](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq). If there can be entire sites for [very obscure cryptocurrencies](https://monero.stackexchange.com/tour), there should be space for this one as well.